# Scraping table with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some particulars rows inside a table but I don't know how to access the information properly. Here is the html:

```
<tr class="even">
  <td style="background: #F5645C; color: #F5645C;">1&#160;</td>
  <td>Michael</td>
  <td class="right">57</td>
  <td class="right">0</td>
  <td class="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td style="background: #8FB9B0; color: #8FB9B0;">1&#160;</td>
  <td>Clara</td>
  <td class="right">48</td>
  <td class="right">0</td>
  <td class="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td style="background: #F5645C; color: #F5645C;">1&#160;</td>
  <td>Lisa</td>
  <td class="right">44</td>
  <td class="right">2</td>
  <td class="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td style="background: #8FB9B0; color: #8FB9B0;">0&#160;</td>
  <td>Joe</td>
  <td class="right">43</td>
  <td class="right">0</td>
  <td class="right">13</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td style="background: #F5645C; color: #F5645C;">1&#160;</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td class="right">38</td>
  <td class="right">3</td>
  <td class="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td style="background: #F5645C; color: #F5645C;">1&#160;</td>
  <td>Francesca</td>
  <td class="right">35</td>
  <td class="right">2</td>
  <td class="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td style="background: #8FB9B0; color: #8FB9B0;">0&#160;</td>
  <td>Carlos</td>
  <td class="right">27</td>
  <td class="right">1</td>
  <td class="right">2</td>
</tr>
```

What I try to obtain, is the text on the next td that comes after every td with the style of color F5645C, but unfortunately I am running into problems.
This is what I want the script to return:
Michael
Lisa
John
Francesca

Here is the code I currently have:

```
table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find('td', style='background: #F5645C; color: #F5645C;').find_next_sibling('td').get_text()
    print(td)
```

On running the script: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'

Comment: The `td` you are trying to hit probably doesn't exist and thus has no next sibling. Style is a terrible selector, can you not use a class or id?

Comment: I can't, I copy pasted the exact html I have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector to select all `<td>` tags that contain attribute `style` with string `color: #F5645C` and then apply method `find_next()`:

```
for td in soup.select('td[style*="color: #F5645C"]'):
  print(td.find_next('td').text)
```

This prints:

```
Michael
Lisa
John
Francesca
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = BeautifulSoup(html)
for tr in data.find_all('tr'):
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    print(td[1].text)
```

Now you can take it further i think..

Comment: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

Use `.findNext("td").text`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    print(tr.td.findNext("td").text)
```

**Output:**

```
Michael
Clara
Lisa
Joe
John
Francesca
Carlos
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `find_all` and a filter for the `style` atribute:

```
 bs = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent)
 bs.find_all('td', attrs={'style':'background-color: #F5645C, color: #F5645C'})
```